# Is this function differentiable at $x = 1$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

I found this problem in a textbook:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < -1 \\
-x & -1 \le x < 0 \\
x & 0 < x \le 1 \\
x^2 & x > 1 \end{cases}$$

And there are two questions: At what values is the function discontinuous and does the derivative of the function exist at $x = 1$?

Here's my thought process: The function is discontinuous at $-1$, and the derivative exists at $1$. I just used the principle that to be continuous and have a derivative at a point, the limit at the point should exist. If we take the limit at $x=1$ as h approaches from the right (thus with the function $x^2$) we should get $1$ and just the same for the limit as h approaches from the left.

What do you think? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What is $f(x)$ at $x=0$?

Comment: As a side note, the verb form of "derivative" is "differentiate" not "derive". You take some formulas and theorems and "derive" another formula or theorem. You "differentiate" a function to find its derivative.

Comment: Good catch Adam. I should probably add that the function is discontinuous at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is discontinous at $x=-1$ and the derivative does not exists at $x=1$ as
$$\frac{d}{dx}x|_{x \rightarrow 1 - (0)}=1$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2|_{x \rightarrow 1 + (0)}=2x|_{x \rightarrow 1 + (0)}=2$$
As you can see $$\frac{d}{dx}x|_{x \rightarrow 1 - (0)} \neq \frac{d}{dx}x^2|_{x \rightarrow 1 + (0)}$$

Comment: hmm, I understand what you mean. But does the fact that the question says f(x) = x when x <= 1 affect the answer in anyway? At the point 1, shouldn't we take the derivative of function x only?

Comment: I just used a sloppy notation, because i dont know how to use the frombottom and fromtop arrow. What i wanted to say is, if you approach $x=1$ from the left you get 1, if you approach $x=1$ from the right you get $2$, hence the derivative at $x=1$ cannot exist.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, thanks!

Comment: Another question asks: Discuss why the function f(x) = abs(x+1) does not have a tangent at x=-1. Showing that the limit does not exist (by computing the one from the right and from the left and showing they are not equal) should do it, right?

Comment: Yes, that would do it :).

Comment: Last question: the function in my first post should be also discontinuous at 0 ?

Comment: No it is continous at $x=0$ as $f(x)$ for $x \rightarrow 0 +(0)$ ist the same  as $f(x)$ for $x \rightarrow 0 -(0)$. Both values are $0$. But it is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Hi again MJay, I just went back on the question of discontinuity, and still, I wonder if the function shouldn't be discontinuous at 0. I mean, it is not even defined at zero.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not defined at $x=0$? I tought you forgot an less/greater-equal sign. If it is not defined at $x=0$ it is automatically not continuous at 0.

Answer (score 0):

From the cases you mentioned, you can easily find out what the derivatives of $f(x)$ will be at different intervals.

Then, test if limit exists for $f(x)$ at $1$ or $-1$ by comparing left hand limit and right hand limit. Then do the same for $f'(x)$ at $1$. That will answer about the differentiability. You can figure out the rest.